# expand template in netbeans 7.0.1 PHP doesn't work

Tags: php, templates, netbeans, code-templates

When I enter an abbreviation of a code template and press the expand key nothing happens. I also get *no suggestions* when i wait for the code completion.

I had a look at Tools > Options > Editor > Code Templates > Language: PHP and there are lots of templates listed. My *Expand template* key is set to *Tab*, but I also tried other keys like *shift + space*.

I did not change the templates, they are still out of the box. I read about the *vdoc* template and because of this I recognized, that expanding templates doesn't work for me.

In *code completion* I activated all options except *case sensitive code completion* for all languages. For the php language I activated: all possible situations, also static, also non-static, all variables and unqualified.

I'm using Netbeans 7.0.1 on Win 7 prof x64.

Why does it not work for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a [bug](http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=200359). It has been fixed since 7.1.

Comment: I'm using netbeans 7.1.1 for two weeks, but I have not tried it again. Now it works perfectly. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your completion must be done in the `<?php` tag.